# Django Restful API returns Empty Json

Tags: python, json, django, api, rest

I'm building a django restful json API using rest_framework libraries, however it returns empty json  [ ] when I submit a request to it, even though there's plenty of records in the DB table. Here' my Code

**models.py**

```
class Member(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, null= False, help_text="Username")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, help_text="Password")
    mobile_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('email', 'mobile', 'username', 'joined_date')
```

**views.py**

```
class MemberAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'member', MemberAPI, base_name='member')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: no errors happening? How are you calling your API?

Comment: no errors or exception, everything works except there's only empty json

Comment: create an `__init__` method inside your `MemberAPI` and add a print statement to see if its called.  Its pretty hard to help you without any debug information available

Answer (score 7):

I got it now. It appears, I was inheriting a base generic class of serialize in
**serializers.py**

I should have inherited from ModelSerializer like this

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('email', 'mobile', 'username', 'joined_date')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vaygeth. I was facing the same issue. This fixed it